# Display latest tag in a commit with multiple tags

Tags: git, git-tag

I have a script for a large project, ten repositories, to checkout branches(local, remote, or tags) and display eventually where each is the current branch in each repository.

I use `git branch` to display which branch or tag is checked out in the current repository. This works fine in most cases except where in the same commit there are multiple tags, resulting in printing a random tag of the ones in that commit.

How can I fix this? Should I implement it in a different way?

Example

```
for repo in ...
do
  cd repo
  git checkout $1 || git checkout $2 || git checkout $3 ....
  git branch ##(to verify what happened)
done
```

So lets say I run `./checkoutAll feat1 origin/feat1 tags/ALL7`
but `ALL7` tag is in the same commit with `ALL6`, 
`git branch` displays the `ALL6` instead of `ALL7` that I specifically asked to checkout.

EDIT: The image below is to assist the people trying to help me,

[image]

So, let's say I run `git checkout tags/V9.00.00.ALL.04`
then git branch displays a random tag (`* detached from ..`) of the ones that exist, 7 in this example.
Is there a way to display the latest? or at least display the one I asked it to checkout (even if the ALL7 is the same with ALL9)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear where you want to show these tags, but let me try to help you.

First, let's find the latest commit hash of the current branch:

```
git rev-parse HEAD
```

Then, let's find all tags:

```
git show-ref --tags --dereference
```

Now that we have both, we can match them to print/show what you're asking. For example:

```
SHA_HEAD=$(git rev-parse HEAD)
ALL_TAGS=$(git show-ref --tags --dereference)
echo "$ALL_TAGS" | awk '/'$SHA_HEAD' refs\/tags\// { print $2 }' | tr '\n' ' '
```

Or in a one-liner:

```
git show-ref --tags --dereference | awk '/'$(git rev-parse HEAD)' refs\/tags\// { print $2 }' | tr '\n' ' '
```

Comment: Of course, this will only show tags that were created for the current commit. Not sure if that's what OP wants.

Comment: wow thats great, I edited the question before working your answer out.

Answer (score 3):

When you check out a tag, you will usually end up with a "headless" checkout, and `git branch` will say:

```
$ git branch
* (detached from TAG)
```

If you want to know which branch this tag is "on", you can check whether your tagged ref is an ancestor of any branches known to your repo. Use

```
$ git branch --contains TAG  # (or HEAD)
```

You will usually get multiple candidates, as any number of branches could have been created after the tag was placed. It would be up to you to decide which one is "the" branch.

If you want to see all the tags pointing at your current checkout ref, use:

```
$ git tag --points-at TAG  # (or HEAD)
```

To see all symbolic refs, use

```
$ git log --oneline --decorate -1
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no way: git doesn't always have the notion that you're on a branch; if you check out a single commit, e.g. by checking out a tag, you're not on a branch, and hence, git can't tell you on which branch you are.

As far as I'm aware, git branch should always print your current branch's name if you're on one, though.